# Fancybox gallery first image isn't showing title

Tags: jquery, fancybox, expressionengine

I work on this site:[Page](http://agnesleppa.fi)

There are Galleries wich are made with fancybox.
Now The thing is on the first Gallery Image, the Imagetitle doesn't show up, but on all the others the show well. I can't figure out why they don't show up in the first image.

Has anyone any Idea why this is the case?

This is the fancybox markup:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="{title}" href="{made_url}" title="{cell_title}">
  <div class="details">
    <div class="center_wrapp">
      <h4>{title}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>    
</a>
<div class="hidden">
  <a class="fancybox" href="{made_url}" rel="{title}" href="{made_url}" title="{cell_title}">                                   
    {cell_title}
  </a>
</div>
```

The Gallery images are all in the hidden div. The first image is loaded from the a tag outside the hidden div. But it should still display the title because the markup is exactely the same???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script at your site which deletes the title of tag A and shows tag H4 over link: user hovers the link and clicks, in this time the script deletes title, but fancybox generates view gallery.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I used a jquery script to hide the title on img hover. I deleted this script and used "data-title-id" for generating the image captions.